# Having trouble adding currency symbol in my project?

Tags: android, android-layout

In My project , I add currency symbol with amount. So i'm using CurrencySymbolConverter ----> to change currency name to symbol.

For example:

```
            code2symbol.put("USD", "$");
            code2symbol.put("CAD", "CA$");
            code2symbol.put("EUR", "€");
```

If adding amount with "USD" ----> $10. I know how to get currency symbol and add with amount.

Here Java Code,

```
ScurrencyCode = detail_object.getString("currency");
sCurrencySymbol = CurrencySymbolConverter.getCurrencySymbol(ScurrencyCode);

friend_earn_amount = sCurrencySymbol+detail_object.getString("friends_earn_amount");
you_earn_amount = sCurrencySymbol+detail_object.getString("your_earn_amount");
```

In this project, I add Saudi Arabian Riyal as currency "﷼" . if Im adding this symbol with amount it will display 5 ﷼. Now I changed this to ﷼S[currency symbol first after that amount]. I need this is my output

So I changed code like this,

```
ScurrencyCode = detail_object.getString("currency");
sCurrencySymbol = CurrencySymbolConverter.getCurrencySymbol(ScurrencyCode);

friend_earn_amount = detail_object.getString("friends_earn_amount")+sCurrencySymbol;
you_earn_amount = detail_object.getString("your_earn_amount")+sCurrencySymbol;
```

Problem :

```
   I change all pages in my app. so it take too long process.
```

Expected output:

```
Is there any easy way to change my whole project.
```

Comment: Is there any easy way to add saudi arabian riyals added before amount  in my whole project.

Comment: You can creat a custom class that  makes the symbol and whenever you need the symbol, you just call the class

Comment: @H.Brooks . Custom class just convert currency name to currency symbol. rgt?

Comment: Yes, the other option would be to store it in sharedPreferences.

Comment: @H.Brooks   I know how to conver currency symbol . My problem is ---> How to set "Saudi Arabian Riyals" currency symbol before amount(value).  Example : ﷼ l .  from my whole project .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear so I will try my best to answer based on the information you have given.

---

> Is there any easy way to change my whole project

You need a reference to the symbol, in other words you need a way to pass the symbol to other Activities.

1. You can do this by either recreating the symbol in each Activity.
2. You can create a custom Class that creates the symbol, in my opinion I wouldn't go for this option, continue reading to see why.
3. Or you can create the symbol once in your `MainActivity` and store
   it in `SharedPreferences` by doing:

   ```
   ScurrencyCode = detail_object.getString("currency");
   sCurrencySymbol = CurrencySymbolConverter.getCurrencySymbol(ScurrencyCode);
   SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
   editor.putString("mySymbol",sCurrencySymbol);
   editor.apply();
   ```

   When ever you need the symbol you can call `SharedPreferences` by calling:

   ```
   SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   String mySymbol = preferences.getString("mySymbol", "");
       if(!mySymbol.equalsIgnoreCase(""){
           myCurrencySymbolAmount = mySymbol + myAmount;
   }
   ```

   The above `myCurrencySymbolAmount` will return your symbol + the amount. Like this :
   ﷼50

---

The problem you are having with placing the current left of the amount is because in Saudi Riyal currency the amount comes first then the symbol.

**What I would do if I was you** is to replace the symbol with `SR` that stands for Saudi riyal.

This will simplify your work because there is no need to create the symbol.

---

The work around if you really want the symbol on the left is to create a drawable/image.